# Under Given conditions, is f absolutely continuous on $[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-measure, uniform-continuity, bounded-variation

1)Let $f: [0,1] \to R$ be a continuous function such that $\mid f(x)-f(y) \mid \le \mid \sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y} \mid $ for all $ x,y \in [0,1]$. Then is $f$ absolutely continuous on $[0,1]$?

2) what about if  $\mid f(x)-f(y) \mid \le \mid x^{1/3}-y^{1/3} \mid $ for all $ x,y \in [0,1]$.

and are both can be bounded variation? justify

These are current problems I am struggling. for me this. I think these function are uniformly continuous. but how can I use this fact to my problems?

please,help me out.

Comment: First write the definition of "absolutely continuous".  Then see what the hypothesis $|f(x)-f(y)| \le |\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}|$ might have to do with it.  Does this suffice to prove it, or if not suggest a way to get a counterexample?  From the wording of the problem, it seems you should do this before you worry about bounded variation.

Comment: I am lost, could you please write some lines.

Comment: First step.  Write the definition of "absolutely continuous".